# DBSCAN clustering - How to choose "Distance" parameter

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I have a dataset where each data point is characterized by two variables: X(time) and Y(volts).

When I plot my data it would be something like this:

[image]

The plot shows some data points created a cluster (I demonstrated those with the red boundary). The other data points are noise points which are not important for me. I finally found "**DBSCAN clustering**" could help finding true data points (points in the red boundary). In particular, two parameters needed to be determined for running this method: (1) Distance (2) MinPts.

I have a question:
**- How I can find a correct value for "eps" (distance)?**

BTW: (1) two variables are not on the same scale. (2) I wanna use R-programming for clustering process.

Comment: Can you post an example dataset that goes with the figure?

Comment: How do you *know* DBSCAN is "the most appropriate" when you apparently did not figure out how to use it? Aldo, please use the search function instead of posting duplicate questions; if possible show your real data rather than an overly simplified sketch.

Comment: Oh, and since your variables are *not* on the same scale, I'd assume *Generalized* DBSCAN may be more appropriate, as you can then treat the two variables independently. Don't just use Euclidean distance!